# Spin-free synchronization primitives

Tags: concurrency, consensus

I'm interested in concurrent algorithms where, if a thread is waiting for a shared resource, it must call a blocking primitive, and not busy-wait. I'll call such algorithms ***spin-free***. Specifically, I'm interested in how powerful synchronization primitives are in terms of what spin-free algorithms can be implemented on top of them.

For example, a [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) is enough to implement exclusive access to a shared resource.

```
M.lock();
resource.access();
M.unlock();
```

On the other hand, the following implementation of a [reader-writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) system (where only one thread may write at a time, but multiple reads may write) is functionally correct (if I haven't made a silly mistake, `R` is the number of concurrent readers, or -1 if there's an active writer), but it is not spin-free, since readers busy-wait if there's an active writer and vice versa.

```
def reader():
    M.lock();
    if R >= 0:
        R += 1;
        M.unlock();
        resource.read();
        M.lock();
        R -= 1;
        M.unlock();
    else:
        M.unlock();
        reader();

def writer():
    M.lock();
    if R >= 0:
        R += 1;
        M.unlock();
        resource.write();
        lock(M);
        R -= 1;
        M.unlock();
    else:
        M.unlock();
        writer();
```

Note that this concept is different from [non-blocking or wait-free synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm). In a spin-free algorithm, a thread may wait for another thread if it's blocked in the execution of a synchronization primitive. What's not ok in either spin-free or wait-free algorithms is for a thread to perform an active loop where it's waiting for some condition to change.

1. Is there a widely accepted term for what I've called “spin-free”? Surely this must have been studied before, and I'd like to find a formal definition (or multiple definitions, if there are multiple sensible way to formalize my informal definition).
2. What I'm really after: is there a hierarchy of expressivity of synchronization primitives for spin-free algorithms? I'd like to find out the spin-free analog of the [consensus number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_(computer_science)#Consensus_number) for wait-free algorithms, if such a thing exists.